# Language design questions on SO

Tags: discussion, scope

So I've seen a couple questions of this type once in a blue moon, and am thinking of asking one, but wasn't sure if this was considered within the realm of SO.

Q: Are questions about programming language design allowed on StackOverflow?

I can find at least two [open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878412/should-primitive-datatypes-be-capitalized) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/366998/good-resources-on-programming-language-design) on the subject, but I recall somewhere long ago reading that such questions weren't appropriate for StackOverflow. So I decided to go ahead and ask.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it's pretty reasonable, myself - particularly as we know that at least one of the C# language designers posts on SO.

Put it this way: I've seen quite a few such questions, and many of them have received interesting answers. There's a certain amount of guesswork required in most cases, but it can be informed guesswork - and sometimes there *is* a definite answer.

Comment: The universe didn't automatically accept your answer soon enough, so I did. I'm accepting this because of "sometimes there _is_ a definite answer." At the end of the day, it's possible to ask fairly sane and definitely answerable questions about language design.

Answer (score 4):

The only way to find out is to ask on SO. There seem to be three basic kind of language design questions - these are my personal opinions on them

- I'm designing my own language - do you think XXXX would be a good feature [ok if community wiki]
- Java has XXXX, why doesn't C++ have it too (or vice versa) [close as S&A]
- Why does XXXX have YYYY [ok if not blindingly obvious]

Comment: Mine's in the first category, and I may not even ask it anymore, but I do agree with your breakdown of the different types of language design questions (and your "try it and see" assertion). Upvotes all around!

Answer (score 2):

I think they're perfectly fine, so long as 1) they aren't thinly-veiled rants about some language feature the author doesn't care for, and 2) they're reasonably specific.

That said, [I gotta agree with Neil](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36850/language-design-questions-on-so/36851#36851) - you're not gonna know how it'll go over 'til you try. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100902/is-lua-interesting-from-a-programming-language-design-perspective) is pretty lousy (IMHO), yet it got one rather nice answer that makes it worth reading... But if Norman Ramsey hadn't responded, it would have been a waste of time - the author could have asked "Why would I want to embed Lua in my app?" and received essentially the same responses.