# The "Language-Design" tag and "Alternative SQL"

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Can we give the moderation at the [language-design](/questions/tagged/language-design) tag a lighter touch than with posts with other tags? Otherwise, I fear that any discussion that tries to introduce innovation will just be shut down as "vague" or "argumentative" before it has a chance to gain traction.

For example, some weeks ago there was an "Alternative SQL" post, using that tag, was very quickly shut down. It started off sounding like a rant (relational model=good, SQL=bad, one I've seen before), but what if, in the second entry, he had made a proposal on a different query syntax, with pros and cons compared to SQL. But there was no second entry, because he got shut down.

Given the way this moderation works, if a fellow posted on the Perl tag, "Hi, I'm Guido, I've got a new language that's a lot like Perl, but easier to read, ... thinking of calling it Python", the Perl moderators would have shut it down as fast as possible.

Making it worse, some of the posts that are shut down are being deleted from the Stack Overflow database altogether, they are just erased (although this does not appear to be the case with the Alternative SQL post in April/May, otherwise I wouldn't know it exists).

Comment: Relevant: [Language design questions on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36850/language-design-questions-on-so).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "second entry"? Why not ask a proper question in the first place? (That's not to say that these kinds of questions don't have it tough on SO. But it may simply not be the ideal place for them.)

Comment: Presumable this is in reference to: [Alternative SQL Dialect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5530330/2509)? Seems to be an invitation to discussion, no?

Comment: While I don't understand other's problems with rants (sometimes you just have to rant), I would think that those kind of questions would belong better on Programmers.

Answer (score 13):

> Can we give the moderation at the "language-design" tag a lighter touch than with posts with other tags?

No, we shouldn't give special treatment to specific tags.  If someone can't communicate their ideas effectively without ranting, then I doubt they're going to give us the next Python.  If they absolutely need to rant in order to create something great, then I'm okay with them ranting somewhere else.