# re golang, is it ok to ask questions regarding language design?

Tags: discussion

go is a new language (which I happen to like a lot) - it is ok to ask questions about it's design and syntax?  or should I seek out another forum for this purpose?

see [in go, why []int instead of int[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6317503/in-go-why-int-instead-of-int)

Comment: Worth reading: [Language design questions on SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36850/language-design-questions-on-so).

Comment: @dori - thanks, did read, and now am even more in the dark as to the negative responses.  perhaps because I am in asia, where people are super polite, this degree of negativity is really disturbing.

Answer (score 2):

So long as it isn't something argumentative, such as "WHY THE HELL WOULD THEY DESIGN IT LIKE XYZ?", it should be just fine. You might want to tag it with [language-design](/questions/tagged/language-design) as well. :)

Comment: thanks for pointers.  will take greater care